# CSS Layout with 2 fixed width columns and 8x 100% width positioning left

Tags: css, grid, multiple-columns

i dont get it...
styling a a layout width 2 fixed width columns (60px each) and 8 x 100% width columns. these 100% columns should be placed from left and each has an overlay:
[image: layout: red: browser, green: 2 fixed width columns, blue: 8x 100% width columns placed from left]

**layout** 
red: browser, green: 2 fixed width columns, blue: 8x 100% width columns placed from left

the grid container is 100% width (and 100vh).
now i don't get it right to calculate the positioning for each blue column from the left side:

```
#thegrid {
    display: block;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.grid {
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:#ccc;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
}
#g1 { left:60px;  z-index: 2;}
#g2 { left:calc(12.5% - 60px);   z-index: 3;}
#g3 { left:calc(25%   - 60px);  z-index: 4;}
#g4 { left:calc(37.5% - 60px);   z-index: 5;}
#g5 { left:calc(50%   - 60px);  z-index: 6;}
#g6 { left:calc(62.5% - 60px); z-index: 7;}
#g7 { left:calc(75%   - 60px);  z-index: 8;}
#g8 { left:calc(87.5% - 60px); z-index: 9;}
#gridleft {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    left:0px;
}
#gridright {
    z-index: 10;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    left:calc(100% - 60px);
    border-right: 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="thegrid" class="clearfix">
    <div class="gridleft" id="gridleft"></div>
    <div id="g1" class="grid"><div class="gridline"></div></div>
    <div id="g2" class="grid"><div class="gridline"></div></div>
    <div id="g3" class="grid"><div class="gridline"></div></div>
    <div id="g4" class="grid"><div class="gridline"></div></div>
    <div id="g5" class="grid"><div class="gridline"></div></div>
    <div id="g6" class="grid"><div class="gridline"></div></div>
    <div id="g7" class="grid"><div class="gridline"></div></div>
    <div id="g8" class="grid"><div class="gridline"></div></div>
    <div class="gridright" id="gridright"></div>
</div>
```

and yes: the columns `.grid` have to be 100% width.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yfomq53g/3/

Comment: As an aside I would recommend you learn about CSS Grid layouts, that way you don't have to create a grid manually.

Comment: i will for ever do a grid manually. only this way i can really do what i really need. but thanks for your input.

Comment: I definitely appreciate the desire to build stuff yourself, but trust me, grid layout is designed for this. Just so long as you are aware of the fact that in this case, you are John Henry, and grid layout is the steam-powered drilling machine (American folk-lore parable). :-)

Answer (score 0):

For your calculation of your `left` property, it may be simpler if you just use something along the lines of `left: calc(60px * (n - 1));`. This will allow take into account having the left sidebar element, but still maintain the same 60px margin between each element.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative
}

.container .grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.container .left,
.container .right {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 100;
}

.container .left {
  left: 0;
}
.container .right {
  right: 0;
}

.container .list:nth-child(1) {
  left: calc(60px * 0);
  z-index: 8;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 25%);
}
.container .list:nth-child(2) {
  left: calc(60px * 1);
  z-index: 7;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 30%);
}
.container .list:nth-child(3) {
  left: calc(60px * 2);
  z-index: 6;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 35%);
}
.container .list:nth-child(4) {
  left: calc(60px * 3);
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 40%);
}
.container .list:nth-child(5) {
  left: calc(60px * 4);
  z-index: 4;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 45%);
}
.container .list:nth-child(6) {
  left: calc(60px * 5);
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 50%);
}
.container .list:nth-child(7) {
  left: calc(60px * 6);
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 55%);
}
.container .list:nth-child(8) {
  left: calc(60px * 7);
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 60%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid left"></div>

  <div class="grid list"></div>
  <div class="grid list"></div>
  <div class="grid list"></div>
  <div class="grid list"></div>
  <div class="grid list"></div>
  <div class="grid list"></div>
  <div class="grid list"></div>
  
  <div class="grid right"></div>
</div>
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your question and I'd be happy to update my answer.

---

Per @Cycle99's comment, I've adjusted the post to better match the request. This time the layering of the items is happening withing the container rather than outside as the initial post had. Thus the calculation ends up being `left: calc(100% * ((n - 1) / 8));`.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative
}

.container .grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.container .left,
.container .right {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 100;
}

.container .center {
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.container .left {
  left: 0;
}

.container .right {
  right: 0;
}

.container .list:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 25%);
}

.container .list:nth-child(2) {
  left: calc(100% * (1 / 8));
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 30%);
}

.container .list:nth-child(3) {
  left: calc(100% * (2 / 8));
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 35%);
}

.container .list:nth-child(4) {
  left: calc(100% * (3 / 8));
  z-index: 4;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 40%);
}

.container .list:nth-child(5) {
  left: calc(100% * (4 / 8));
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 45%);
}

.container .list:nth-child(6) {
  left: calc(100% * (5 / 8));
  z-index: 6;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 50%);
}

.container .list:nth-child(7) {
  left: calc(100% * (6 / 8));
  z-index: 7;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 55%);
}

.container .list:nth-child(8) {
  left: calc(100% * (7 / 8));
  z-index: 8;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 60%);
}

.container .list:nth-child(9) {
  left: calc(100% * (8 / 8));
  z-index: 8;
  background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 60%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid left"></div>

  <div class="container center">
    <div class="grid list"></div>
    <div class="grid list"></div>
    <div class="grid list"></div>
    <div class="grid list"></div>
    <div class="grid list"></div>
    <div class="grid list"></div>
    <div class="grid list"></div>
    <div class="grid list"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but the container should be flexible in width and as a result the .grid columns too. each of the columns should have the same overlay (left) to the next, even if i scale the browser width. only the left and right column stay in fixed width (60px). let me know if i'm imprecisely!

Comment: @Cycle99 I've adjusted the post to hopefully better match your request.